# Achievement tagging by game or service.

Tags: discussion, tags

I have been tagging my StarCraft 2 questions that deal with achievements with `starcraft-2`, `achievements`, and `starcraft-2-achievements`. The starcraft-2-achievements tags keep being removed by other users. I wouldn't care except I added the tags to the posts because there are `steam-achievements` and `live-achievements` in the system.

What stance do we want to take on game / service achievement tagging?

**Achievements in relation to other tags**

- `starcraft-2` `achievements`
- `live` `achievements`

**vs. achievements attached to their service / game**

- `starcraft-2-achievements` `starcraft-2`
- `live-achievements` `live`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest we use [achievements] for all of these. Do we really need a [bunny-must-die-achievements] tag, which might be seen all of once or twice, as an example?

I think [achievements] is the kind of tag that works very well using context of other tags, because any necessary point to those achievements should already be a tag whether it is the platform or the game. For example, a [question about XBox Live achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/how-do-xbox-live-achievements-work-if-youre-offline) can be understood by the presence of [xbox-live] [achievements], since it is verily a question about XBox Live as well.

Comment: As one of those people who did aforementioned removing, I agree with Grace, as this was the basis for my own logic.

Answer (score 4):

My opinion (and it's only my opinion) is that per game tag should not be used, and per system can be used (or not).

`achievements` is a correct tag, which can go hand to hand with the game tag, for example tagging `starcraft-2` and `achievements` it's very clear what you're talking about, which would make `starcraft-2-achievements` unnecessary.

There could be a question about `live-achievements` and `steam-achievements` specifically, so it's ok for this tags to exist, but I wouldn't use them when talking about a specific game, where I would use the more general `achievements` tag